Inserting elements in a list in Python
I have a list x0. I want to insert indices according to elements of missing_values. I present the current and expected output.
x0 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
missing_values = [2, 4]  # indices to set to zero

# Create a set of indices from missing_values
indices_to_set_zero = set(missing_values)

# Initialize the result list
result = []

# Iterate through x0
for i, value in enumerate(x0):
    # If the index is in the set, append 0 before the value
    if i in indices_to_set_zero:
        result.append(0)
    result.append(value)

# If the last index is in the set, append a 0 at the end
if len(x0) in indices_to_set_zero:
    result.append(0)

print(result)

The current output is
[1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5]

The expected output is
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5]


You have forgot to adjust the position of insertion due to insertion ...

I think the expected output should be [1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5] according to your explanation

reverse your loop: for i, value in reversed(enumerate(x0))

It says not reversible.

@user23495528 Can you clarify the "If the last index is in the set, append a 0 at the end" requirement, preferrably with an example?

Construct a list as you go and check if current amount of items matches index contained in missing values:
x0 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
missing_values = {2, 4, 5, 7}

out = []

for el in x0:
    while len(out)+1 in missing_values:
        out.append(0)
    out.append(el)
#to handle indexes at the end
while len(out)+1 in missing_values:
    out.append(0)
print(out) # [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 5]

(adding 1 to len(out) is needed as lists are 0-indexed)

This will have to be expanded for the case, where the last index is in the set, e.g. missing_values = {2, 7}, which seems to important according to the last lines in the original question.

@Nyps Addressed that, also fixed the issue should there be consecutive indexes to put 0 at.

What about output for x0 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ] ?

x0 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ],  missing_values = {2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19, 21, 24} gives interesting output: [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 7]

@Claudio What do you think it should be?

It is unknown what is should be. The OP haven't specified how to handle edge cases, what makes a poor question leaving much room for deliberate interpretation.It seems OP doesn't care anyway.

You code does not address the requirement in the question code of adding a zero at the end of the sequence, but your answer is accepted one, so ... nevermind ... seems not to matter ...

As @user24803130 said, Python lists are zero-indexed. If you want your indices to start at 1, you will have to deduct that.
You can make use of the list's insert function:
x0 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
missing_values = [2, 4]  # indices to set to zero

for i in missing_values:
    x0.insert(i-1, 0)

print(x0)

This will give you your expected output:
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5]

Note, that this code expects missing values to be an ordered list. If this is not the case you may replace missing_values in the for loop by sorted(missing_values).

Since Lists are indexed from 0
you need to subtract 1 so it will end on index 1 and 3
Also we make a copy of a x0 so we dont break indexing via enumerate
and we only insert 0 on a positions that need inserting without any need of going through the full loop
x0 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
missing_values = [2, 4]


result = x0[:]


for i, position in enumerate(missing_values):
    # Convert 1-based position to 0-based index and adjust for previous insertions
    index_to_insert = position - 1
    # Insert zero at the calculated index
    result.insert(index_to_insert, 0)

print(result)


You seem to have two issues in the code.
First, lists are 0-indexed, meaning that the first position in the list is list[0] and not list[1]. This can easily be fixed in your code:
x0 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
missing_values = [2, 4]  # indices to set to zero

# Create a set of indices from missing_values
indices_to_set_zero = set(missing_values)

# Initialize the result list
result = []

# Iterate through x0
for i, value in enumerate(x0):
    # If the index is in the set, append 0 before the value
    if (i + 1) in indices_to_set_zero: # (i + 1) to account for 0-indexing
        result.append(0)
    result.append(value)

# If the last index is in the set, append a 0 at the end
if len(x0) in indices_to_set_zero:
    result.append(0)

print(result)

An alternative to doing it this way would be to just set correct indices in missing_values.
Second, since you are appending 0 to result your subsequent appends are offset. This could be solved by changing the layout of your for-loop, try this code:
x0 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
missing_values = [2, 4]  # indices to set to zero

# Create a set of indices from missing_values
indices_to_set_zero = set(missing_values)

# Initialize the result list
result = []

# Iterate through len(x0) + len(missing_values)
x0_index = 0
for i in range(len(x0) + len(missing_values)):
    # Either append a zero or append from the x0 list
    if (i + 1) in indices_to_set_zero:
        result.append(0)
    else:
        result.append(x0[x0_index])
        x0_index += 1

print(result)

Note that this also gets rid of your check for the last indexed zero.
I hope this gives you some guidance

The second solution could be shorter if you use an iterator instead of an index.
